# What am I doing wrong with this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have some jQuery/JavaScript code that detects the device orientation and modifies the CSS for the navbar accordingly to the device orientation. It works perfectly when you open the navbar in the device orientation but when the navbar is already open and you change the device orientation it breaks and stays the same as the previous orientation.

I've already tried a few if/else statements and a few do/while statements but could not get them how I would like it.

My jQuery/JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".closebtn, .navbar-fullscreen-background").on('touchstart', function() {
    $('.navbar-background').css({
      'width': 90 + 'px',
      'height': 90 + 'px',
      'left': 2 + 'vw',
      'top': 30 + 'px',
    });
    $('.fadein-test, .fadein-test2, .fadein-test3, .fadein-test4').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').fadeIn(200);
    }, 300);
    $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').fadeOut(300);
    $('.closebtn').css('display', 'none');
  });
  $('.fadein-test, .closebtn').hide();

  function doOnOrientationChange() {
    switch (window.orientation) {
      case 90:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css({
            'width': 1450 + 'px',
            'height': 1200 + 'px',
            'left': -400 + 'px',
            'top': -750 + 'px',
          });
          $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'block');
          $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'none');
          $('.fadein-test').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest');
          $('.fadein-test2').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest2');
          $('.fadein-test3').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest3');
          $('.fadein-test4').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest4');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.closebtn').fadeIn(200);
          }, 300);
        });
        break;
      case -90:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css({
            'width': 1450 + 'px',
            'height': 1200 + 'px',
            'left': -400 + 'px',
            'top': -750 + 'px',
          });
          $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'block');
          $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'none');
          $('.fadein-test').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest');
          $('.fadein-test2').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest2');
          $('.fadein-test3').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest3');
          $('.fadein-test4').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest4');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.closebtn').fadeIn(200);
          }, 300);
        });
        break;
      case 0:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css({
            'width': 1450 + 'px',
            'height': 1200 + 'px',
            'left': -400 + 'px',
            'top': -400 + 'px',
          });
          $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'block');
          $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'none');
          $('.fadein-test').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest');
          $('.fadein-test2').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest2');
          $('.fadein-test3').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest3');
          $('.fadein-test4').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest4');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.closebtn').fadeIn(200);
          }, 300);
        });
        break;
      case 180:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css({
            'width': 1450 + 'px',
            'height': 1200 + 'px',
            'left': -400 + 'px',
            'top': -400 + 'px',
          });
          $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'block');
          $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'none');
          $('.fadein-test').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest');
          $('.fadein-test2').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest2');
          $('.fadein-test3').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest3');
          $('.fadein-test4').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest4');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.closebtn').fadeIn(200);
          }, 300);
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

  // Initial execution if needed
  doOnOrientationChange();
});
```

I would like it to be able to detect the device orientation change and change the CSS accordingly while the navbar is open as well and not change the CSS to just that CSS for that orientation before it is opened. Thank you.

Comment: for a start your indentation is unnecessary, and your orientation is changed 'ontouchstart'

Comment: Dear Cody, could you check wether your
doOnOrientationChange is fired or not when orientation change adding a console.log('fired') or alert ('fired')  AFTER function doOnOrientationChange() {

Comment: doOnOrientationChange is fired once the page loads and when it detects a change in the device orientation

Comment: This would be a lot easier to debug if you didn't repeat all that code for each case and only switched a few variables then use one instance of those long code blocks at the end. Would make it so much easier to see what the differences are case by case

Comment: There is `window.addEventListener("resize", function(){....})` (or `$(window).on("resize",function(){....})` in Jquery) event you should have a try with.

Comment: One serious issue is you keep adding event listeners every orientation change. Adding one does not remove existing ones. That is likely the root of your problem

Comment: I have tried doing stuff like case: 90 || -90 and case: 90 && -90 it does not work. It only always works for -90 not 90. That is why i have that many cases

Comment: Do you understand my point though about the event listeners? This whole approach looks completely backwards.

Comment: Having multiple cases is fine. But having multiple listeners is not. Also going to need to keep track of orientation when each event occurs so if it has changed when next one occurs you know what should be different

Comment: What it boils down to is use one event listener with different orientation cases inside that event handler. And those cases need to include what orientation was last time event occured

Comment: I added 'orientationchange' to all of my $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() and it actually works the way i would like it to now. So basically like this. $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart orientationchange', function(). Edit: when i change the device orientation before i open he navbar it opens on itself so its not 100%

Comment: As an FYI - jQuery css() dimensions don't need a `'px'` string added to them....it knows to add it for numeric values. And don't need to quote the properties that aren't hyphenated...cuts down on typing

Comment: The syntax to do the same thing in multiple cases is `case 90: case -90:`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. It's been awhile since I've done switch statements

Comment: I'm basically trying to find a way to make it detect that its been open and change the CSS if the device rotates with the navbar open. If you rotate it before opening its fine. If you rotate while it is open it breaks. I tried a way earlier that sort of worked while it was open it worked fine but if it was closed and then you rotate it open by itself and i do not want it to do that.

Answer (score 3):

As I read through your code, I think most of it could be done with **CSS** instead of **JS**, using the `@media (orientation: landscape) {} /* or portrait */`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation

**EDIT**

Anyways, I think restructuring the code may make it a bit easier to understand where it breaks:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // starting background
  var bgNavInitObj = {
    'width': 90 + 'px',
    'height': 90 + 'px',
    'left': 2 + 'vw',
    'top': 30 + 'px',
  };

  // 90 and -90 positions
  var bgNav90 = {
    'width': 1450 + 'px',
    'height': 1200 + 'px',
    'left': -400 + 'px',
    'top': -750 + 'px',
  };

  // 0 and 180 positions
  var bgNav0 = {
    'width': 1450 + 'px',
    'height': 1200 + 'px',
    'left': -400 + 'px',
    'top': -400 + 'px',
  };

  // setting transitions
  function setTransitions() {
    $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').fadeIn(300).css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'none');
    $('.fadein-test').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest');
    $('.fadein-test2').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest2');
    $('.fadein-test3').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest3');
    $('.fadein-test4').show().addClass('fadein-animationtest4');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.closebtn').fadeIn(200);
    }, 300);
  }

  function changeBg() {
    switch (window.orientation) {
      case 90:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css(bgNav90);
        });
        break;
      case -90:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css(bgNav90);
        });
        break;
      case 0:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css(bgNav0);
        });
        break;
      case 180:
        $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
          $('.navbar-background').css(bgNav0);
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    // this function is always executed
    setTransitions();
  }

  $(".closebtn, .navbar-fullscreen-background").on('touchstart', function() {
    $('.navbar-background').css(bgNavInitObj);
    $('.fadein-test, .fadein-test2, .fadein-test3, .fadein-test4').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').fadeIn(200);
    }, 300);
    $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').fadeOut(300);
    $('.closebtn').css('display', 'none');
  });
  $('.fadein-test, .closebtn').hide();

  // this is your touchstart function
  // with the changeBg() it uses the needed functions depending on
  // window.orientation
  $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
    changeBg();
  });

  // this may be a code smell, but I supposed that you may want to
  // do other things on orientation change
  function doOnOrientationChange() {
    changeBg();
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tried that way before because it was easier but it does not work the way i want it. Plus way too many ```@keyframes``` and stuff so i just add ```transition:``` to my classes and update depending on orientation.

Comment: Personal taste, I guess - if you tried CSS, and it doesn't do what you want, then JS is your way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't do anything in `doOrientationChange()` other than add new event listeners I think you should get rid of it completely.

Instead use one listener and each time the touchstart occurs store the current orientation. Then when it closes check if orientation is the same. I used jQuery data() to store and get the previous state

It's hard to help rewrite this without seeing the markup so here's a basic high level conceptual outline using some pseudo code. Hopefully this will give you some  ideas to work with that are far easier to debug as well as to DRY out the code

```
// cache references to elements in variables for code simplification 
// and not needing to search dom each time and much easier to write 
// variables than long selectors repeatedly

var $nav_parent = $(selector??)
  .data('navState', { open: false, orient: window.orientation}),
  // store state on parent or button?
  $nav_bg = $('.navbar-background'),
  $nav_btn = $(".mobile-navbar-button");

$nav_bg.on('touchstart', function(evt) {
  var prevState = getNavState(),
    prevOrient = prevState.orient,
    currOrient = window.orientation;

  setNavState(currOrient, false)
  $nav_bg.css(getNavBgCss(currOrient, prevOrient, false));

});

$nav_btn.on('touchstart', function(evt) {
  var prevState = getNavState(),
    prevOrient = prevState.orient,
    currOrient = window.orientation;    

  // store state when it opens
  setNavState(currOrient, true);

  $nav_bg.css(getNavBgCss(currOrient, prevOrient, true));

});

// helper functions
function getNavState() {
  // want to store somehwere else? easier to change in one helper function than numerous places
  return $nav_parent.data('navState')
}

function setNavState(orient, isOpen) {
  var currState = {
    orient: orient,
    open: isOpen
  };
  $nav_parent.data('navState', currState)

}
// this ones a bit ugly...but gives ideas on how to manage various conditions
function getNavBgCss(orient, prevOrient, isOpen) {
  // now have access to all possible conditions
  var isSame = orient === prevOrient,
    is90 = Math.abs(orient) === 90;

  // adjust based on orientation differences , not real logic, only conceptual

  return {
    'width': 1450, // no need for 'px' prefix
    'height': 1200,
    'left': is90 ? isSame ? -700 : -200 : isSame ? -200 : 700, // 
    'top': -750,
  }

}
```